# How to override service declaration with import

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In config/services.yaml I have a standard configuration:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true 
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false 

App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

I would like to custom configuration in other file:

```
config/custom/services.yml
```

In this file I have declaration:

```
services:
    App\Updates\SiteUpdateManager:
        arguments:
            $adminEmail: '%admin_email%'
```

And I'm doing at the end of file config/services.yaml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config/custom/services.yml }
```

But still on the name "App\Updates\SiteUpdateManager" I have autowired service.

I can change name in file config/custom/services.yml:

```
services:
    App\Updates\SiteUpdateManager_new:
        arguments:
            $adminEmail: '%admin_email%'
```

And then it is working ok, but I would like to override this.

Comment: Try place custom service configuration in a same file where autowire was difined

Comment: @Gedweb I know, it working, but I would like to use imports.